# matplotlib contour input array order

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

**Question**: what order does the contour from matplotlib expect for the input 2D array?

**Elaborate**: Matplotlib contour documentation says that the routine call is

```
x_axis = np.linspace(10,100,n_x)
y_axis = np.linspace(10,100,n_y)
matplotlib.pyplot.contour(x_axis, y_axis, scalar_field)
```

Where scalar_field must be a 2D array. For example, the scalar_field can be generated by

```
scalar_field = np.array( [(x*y) for x in x_axis for y in y_axis])
scalar_field = scalar_field.reshape(n_x, n_y)
```

If scalar_field is given to contour,

```
plt.contour(x_axis, y_axis,scalar_field) #incorrect
```

the orientation of the plot is incorrect (rotated). To restore the proper orientation the scalar_field must be transposed:

```
plt.contour(x_axis, y_axis,scalar_field.transpose()) #correct
```

So what is the order that contour expect that scalar_field has?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should plot using `contour` passing also 2-D arrays for `X` and `Y`, then each point in your `scalar_field` array will correspond to a coordinate `(x, y)` in `X` and `Y`. You can conveniently create `X` and `Y` using `numpy.meshgrid`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_axis, y_axis, copy=False, indexing='xy')
plt.contour(X, Y, scalar_field)
```

The argument `indexing` can be changed to `'ij'` if you want the `x` coordinate to represent line and `y` to represent column, but in this case `scalar_fied` must be calculated using `ij` indexing.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the indexing part and the ordering?

Comment: @Ivan When you use `'xy'` indexing you can imagine you looking at the matrix from above and the x coordinate going from the left to the right, while the y coordinate from the bottom to the top. This is not what you want sometimes, so that you have the option to use `'ij'` indexing, where the first index can be seen as line and the second as column...

Answer (score 3):

The `x` values are expected to correspond to the *columns* of data, not the rows (i.e., `x` is the horizontal axis and `y` is the vertical axis). You have it reversed, which is why you are having to transpose the `z` values to make it work.

To avoid requiring the transpose, create your array as:

```
scalar_field = np.array( [(x*y) for y in y_axis for x in x_axis])
scalar_field = scalar_field.reshape(n_y, n_x)
```

Comment: Could you please explain where in the documentation it says what you are saying about x and y?

Comment: The `contour` doc string for matplotlib 1.2.1 states "*X* and *Y* must both be 2-D with the same shape as *Z*, or they must both be 1-D such that ``len(X)`` is the number of columns in *Z* and ``len(Y)`` is the number of rows in *Z*."

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly my question: len(x) is the _first_ index, so the reshape must obey that, and so the correct answer is reshape(n_x, n_y), and not the other way around. That's why is confusing.

Comment: Your confusion is understandable and is due to the differences between numpy array addressing and the matplotlib 2D coordinate space used by `contour`. You didn't get an error with the `reshape` call because numpy will gladly reshape your array to any shape that keeps the number of elements the same. But the answer is still the same: the first index into your `Z` array (as specified by numpy) corresponds to the *rows* of the array but the `X` array passed to `contour`  (as specified by matplotlib) should correspond to the *columns* of `Z`.